# How to create global user in C# WinForms app (credentials)?

Tags: c#, winforms, authentication

I have a user log-in form with username and password - I want to save them globally so that they can be available after the log-in. I try to do this with the following code:

```
 namespace PassManager
    {
      struct SesUser
        {
            int id;
            string username;
            string password;
        }
       public class US
        {
            SesUser uu;
        }

    }
```

I try to declare a `public class` with only one member `SesUser` and I want to access that user in all of my `cs` files. I would like to ask if this is the correct way to do so or there are better ways to accomplish this task?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go to `Project > Add Item > Class` and call it `CurrentUser`

Then inside it create `public static parameters`

`Static` creates object which is accessible through class name itself (not an object which is created from the class)

So example of `CurrentUser` class is like this:

```
public static class CurrentUser
{
    public static string Name; //Accessible with CurrentUser.Name
    public static string FamilyName; //Accessible with CurrentUser.FamilyName
    public static int Age; //Accessible with CurrentUser.Age

    public bool initialized = false //Accessible only through object which is created using CurrentUser

}
```

So now you can access first 3 variables from any class within same `namespace` like this:

```
public class SomeRandomClass
{
    string ThisUserName = CurrentUser.Name;
    string ThisUserFamilyName = CurrentUser.FamilyName;

    CurrentUser.Age = 15;
}
```

Static objects are accessible from any class within same namespace. Change to static object from one class will affect that object in other classes so be careful when you are making changes.

More info about `Access Modifiers` could be found [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/access-modifiers)

Answer (score 0):

You can create one global class which will hold authenticated user name and then access will be available if that class user name is not null.

or You can refer this link provided by Microsoft

[How to: Implement User Login with Client Application Services](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/common-client-technologies/how-to-implement-user-login-with-client-application-services)

Answer (score 0):

Make your `US` class static then you can access it from anywhere:

```
public static class US
{
    public static SesUser uu { get; set; }
}
```

Then you can access it with:

```
US.uu
```

E.G.

```
System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine($"{US.uu.id} {US.uu.username} {US.uu.password}");
```